# Check two SQL tables

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have 2 MySQL tables;

`portal.campaignAccount_Relations`:

```
+------------+----------+---------+
| relationID | campaign | account |
+------------+----------+---------+
| 1          | 1        | 1       |
| 2          | 2        | 1       |
| 3          | 4        | 1       |
| 4          | 3        | 2       |
+------------+----------+---------+
```

and `portal.campaign_queue`:

```
+----+----------------------------+---------+
| id | title                      | deleted |
+----+----------------------------+---------+
| 1  | Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet | 0       |
| 2  | Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet | 0       |
| 3  | Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet | 1       |
| 4  | Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet | 0       |
+----+----------------------------+---------+
```

I want to find all rows of `portal.campaignAccount_Relations` where the `deleted` field of `portal.campaign_queue` is `0` for the associated campaign.

I am new to the INNER JOIN MySQL function and am having trouble finding support for this type of query. I tried:

```
SELECT campaignAccount_Relations.campaign, campaignAccount_Relations.account
FROM campaignAccount_Relations 
INNER JOIN campaign_queue 
    ON campaign_queue.deleted = 0 AND campaign_queue.id=campaignAccount_Relations.campaign
```

and got the values I was looking for. Is this the correct/most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Please give it a try, that's how you learn. You won't learn if we just write it for you.

Comment: If you can't get it working, post your attempt and we'll show you where you went wrong.

Comment: @Barmar thanks. I tried this:
`SELECT campaignAccount_Relations.campaign, campaignAccount_Relations.account FROM campaignAccount_Relations INNER JOIN campaign_queue ON campaign_queue.deleted = 0 AND campaign_queue.id=campaignAccount_Relations.campaign` and got the values I was looking for. Is this the correct/most efficient way to do this?

Comment: It's close. `campaign_queue.deleted = 0` should be in `WHERE` clause, because it's not a relationship between the tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query will work, but conditions that aren't related to both tables should usually be in `WHERE`, not `ON` (an exception is when doing outer joins -- conditions on the secondary table need to be in the `ON` clause).

```
SELECT campaignAccount_Relations.campaign, campaignAccount_Relations.account
FROM campaignAccount_Relations 
INNER JOIN campaign_queue ON campaign_queue.id=campaignAccount_Relations.campaign
WHERE campaign_queue.deleted = 0
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bff4e/1)

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Could you help me with one more problem?
I also want to find DISTINCT values only. I tried putting DISTINCT after SELECT but the values I received from the table did not change. Any ideas as to why this happens?

Comment: I don't see any duplicates in your sample data.

Comment: The actual data is different but I am unable to share the real data at the current time.

Comment: I will put together an SQL fiddle with a better representation of the actual data.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT` applies to all the columns in the `SELECT` list, not just one column. If you want to make one column distinct, use `GROUP BY columnName`.

Comment: [DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3020d/1) here is the updated SQL Fiddle with some better data. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: I don't see any duplicate results. Campaign 2 appears twice, but it has a different account.

Comment: Account 1 appears 3 times, but it has different campaigns in each.

Answer (score -1):

You should just start trying different things, as its the best way to learn. Here is my help for you using a left join:

```
SELECT * FROM portal.campaignAccount_Relations car
LEFT JOIN proal.campaign_que cq ON car.relationId = cq.id 
WHERE cq.deleted=0
```

or maybe you want the following, not sure which column is your relational column for campaigns...

```
SELECT * FROM portal.campaignAccount_Relations car
LEFT JOIN proal.campaign_que cq ON car.campaign = cq.id 
WHERE cq.deleted=0
```

From mysql.com:

> In MySQL, JOIN, CROSS JOIN, and INNER JOIN are syntactic equivalents (they can replace each other)

I didn't test any of this, so you may have to adjust syntax, etc...

Comment: `left join` is not the correct join here. It only works because the  `where` clause turns it into an `inner join` automatically

Comment: good to know, it would work though right, not saying its necessarily best practice.

Comment: It is the wrong practice. And we should not teach people the wrong practice, should we?